# Ошибка авторизации по номеру Telegram Python telethon

Tags: python, telethon

имеется код, который создает сессию по номеру

```
def create_client(number):
    try:
        print("Создание подключения по номеру:", str(number), ". Если запросит ввести номер, то введите его, а потом введите номер кода")
        client = TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash).start()
        clients.append(client)
    except errors.PhoneNumberBannedError:
        print("Аккаунт "+str(number)+ " забанен")
    except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
        print("Аккаунт не сможет выполнять некоторое время действия:", e , "Возможно вы уже вошли в парсере с этого аккаунта")
    except errors.PhoneNumberInvalidError as e:
        print("Не валидный номер.", e)
```

Я вызвал этот метод, передав номер из китая `8618336439723`

Но с ним выкидывает ошибку:

```
оздание подключения по номеру: 8618336439723 . Если запросит ввести номер, то введите его, а потом введите номер кода
2019-01-12 17:16:43,137 INFO:Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
2019-01-12 17:16:43,177 INFO:Connection to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
Please enter your phone (or bot token): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 569, in <module>
    create_client("8618336439723")
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 182, in create_client
    client = TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash).start()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 114, in start
    else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 129, in _start
    value = phone()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 19, in <lambda>
    phone=lambda: input('Please enter your phone (or bot token): '),
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Выкинуло ошибку, я даже не успел ввести код
Использую библиотеку telethon

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка оказалась в среде разработки PyCharm, запустил из под cmd, все заработало